# Let p be a prime. If a group has more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$, then prove that the group can't be cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

**Result:** *Let G be a group which has more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$. I need to prove that such a group can't be cylic. $p$ is a prime number.* 
 
 Let's consider the case when G is finite. I want to prove the result using contradiction.

 **Proof:**  On the contrary, assume that G is cyclic. Hence, there exists $a\in G$ such that $G=<a>$. Let $|G|=n$ 
 
**Case 1:** $p$ divides $n$ 
In this case, no. of elements of order $p =\phi (p)$, where $\phi$ is Euler Phi function.
Since it is known that, $\phi (p)\le p-1$, we have a contradiction. 
 
**Case 2:** $p$ doesn't divide $n$ 
gcd $(p,n)=1$ 
Let $|a^p|=t$. This implies that $a^{pt}=e$, where $e$ is identity of $G$. 
$\implies$ $n$ divides $pt \implies \exists$ integer $k$ such that $ kn=pt$. How do I arrive at a contradiction from here?

PS: I don't know Lagrange's theorem, Cosets, Sylow's theorem, Isomorphisms yet.

Comment: Compare it with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368376/let-p-be-a-prime-if-a-group-has-more-than-p-%E2%88%92-1-elements-of-order-p-why).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I don't know Lagrange's theorem, Sylow theorem, Cosets etc. yet. In the duplicate answer, you suggest there is mention of kernel which I don't know yet. That's why, I had asked this question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, This is an exercise problem in Gallian's Abstract Algebra (Exercise 
 53 of Chapter 4: Cyclic Groups), Lagrange's theorem is not introduced until chapter 7 of the book.

Comment: (@DietrichBurde I deleted my comment before you replied as I figured that I should work out the solution before making such bold claims! I agree with your point though that it should be learned, but it is always nice to stay on our toes and not use theorems when it isn't necessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof without using Lagrange's theorem. Suppose $p$ does not divide $|G|=n$. Since $G=\langle a\rangle $ we must have $|a|=n$. Now, by our assumption there is an element $x\in G$ or order $p$. Since it is an element in the group there must be some $0\leq t\leq n-1$ such that $x=a^t$. Then:

$a^{pt}=x^p=e$

$n$ is the order of $a$, so this implies $n|pt$. But by our assumption $\gcd(p,n)=1$, so we conclude that $n|t$. But since $0\leq t\leq n-1$ this implies $t=0$. So $x=a^0=e$. It is a contradiction because $e$ has order $1$, not $p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At first, I didn't understand the contradiction argument you have used. Then I noticed that $x$ was assumed to be of order $p$ and finally it was deduced that $x=e$ which can't be the case since $p$ is prime. Why didn't I see that $n|pt \implies n|t$. :)

Answer (score 2):

To complete your missing case it is enough to prove that if $G$ is a non-trivial, cyclic group of order $n$ and $\gcd(p, n)=1$ then there is no non-trivial element $a$ in $G$ such that $a^p$ is trivial. (This is simply a special case of Lagrange's theorem for cyclic groups, but it's proof is elementary.)

To see this, suppose $a^p=e$ the identity. As $\gcd(p, n)$ are coprime, there are integers $k, l\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $kp+ln=1$. Therefore, as $a^{ln}=(a^n)^l=e^l=e$, we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
a^{kp+ln}&=a^1\\
a^{kp}&=a\\
(a^{p})^k&=a\\
e^k&=a
\end{align*}
$$
This is a contradiction, as $e^k=e$ (and $a\neq e$ as $G$ is non-trivial).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have understood it.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is infinite, then $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. But $\mathbb{Z}$ has no element
with finite order except the identity. So assume $ G$ is finite and cyclic. Let
$a ∈ G$ and $∣a∣ = p$. Then for any $e ≠ b ∈ ⟨a⟩$,  order of $b$ divides $p$ and $∣b∣ = p$.
Hence, $⟨a⟩$ contains $p−1$ elements of order $p$. By the hypothesis, there exists $c ∉ ⟨a⟩$
such that $∣c∣ = p$. Then $⟨c⟩$ is another subgroup of $G$ with order $p$. But by the
Fundamental Theorem of Cyclic Groups, $G$ can have only one subgroup of order $p$,
we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $G$ is either an infinite cyclic group or a cyclic group of finite order $n$, with generator $g$. Then, there are three cases:

> **Case 1**: $G$ is finite, and $p$ divides $n$, let's say $n=kp$.

In this case, the elements of order $p$ are the non-identity elements of $G$ whose $p$th power is the identity. If $(g^m)^p=e$, then $n=kp \vert mp$, so $k \vert m$. The number of positive multiples of $k$ less than $n=kp$ is exactly equal to $p-1$, so $G$ has exactly $p-1$ elements of order $p$.

> **Case 2**: $G$ is finite, and $p$ does not divide $n$.

In this case, suppose that $(g^m)^p=e$. Then, $n \vert mp$, and since $n$ and $p$ are coprime, $n \vert m$. Hence, $g^m=e$, so $G$ has no elements of order $p$.

> **Case 3**: $G$ is infinite.

In this case, the group $G$ is torsion-free, so it cannot have any elements of order $p$.

The above proves that if $G$ is cyclic, then it has either $0$ or $p-1$ elements of order $p$. By contraposition, if $G$ has more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$, then it cannot be cyclic.

Comment: In case 3, G is torsion free. What is torsion free?